# Display WFS layer in ol3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-3

I'm working with geoserver and openlayers 3, i have a hosted layer in geoserver that i want display using ol3 as a wfs layer. it doesn't show any errors, but i dont get the map. it works with wms, but not wfs.
I'm using wamp server to host my application.

Please can anyone help me to fix that? This is my code :

```
var v=new ol.layer.Vector({
       source: new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.WFS({
                version: '1.1.0',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',
                featurePrefix: 'opengeo', 
                featureType: 'comgeo', 
                featureNS: 'http://localhost:8080/opengeo', 
                geometryName: 'geom'
            })
        })  
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map-id',
    layers: [v],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',

        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
    })     
});
```

i read in forums that i need to set proxy, i did that and my proxy works fine, but i dont know how to it use in my code (Openlayers.ProxyHost).
When i use firebug, under network/images tab, i can see wms requests, but not for wfs.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem, so I want to share the solution with you.

First thing there were some mistakes in my previous code, this the right way to set a `wfs` layer :

```
var u = "http://localhost/geoserver/wfs?&service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=opengeo:comgeo";
var v = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'comgeo',
           source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: '/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url='+ encodeURIComponent(u),

                format: new ol.format.WFS({

                })
           })   
});
```

`u` is the wfs request, the paramvalue `opengeo` is the workspace in geoserver, and `comgeo` is the layer.

You need to escape this url by using `encodeURIComponent` function, so you don't get the famous error like :

> Could not determine geoserver request from http request

The first part of my url `/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=` is that because you need a proxy if your application is running from another location (I'm using `wamp` to host mine).

To get your proxy working try this tutorial:
[set proxy](http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html)

Use the proxy like in my code, this

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
```

is not available in `ol3`.

Comment: Man I was trying 10 hours to find how this thing works and finally thanks to you I made it. Its ridiculous how everyone copies and pastes useless answers regarding jsonp etc. None of these things worked for me. But your answer did the trick. Thanks a lot for your time to post it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing up OpenLayers 2 and OpenLayers 3. Please take a look at [this](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-wfs.html) or [this](http://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter03_08_loading_strategies.html) example. These examples are using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) so that you don't need a proxy.

Comment: Thank u for reply, is there a way to do that without using JSONP?

Comment: i think i have another problem, i just made my app in jetty/webapps, but wfs layer is not displayed.. so it's not about cors