# Editing feature in OpenLayers2 published by geoserver and saving the updated in postgres connected database table

Tags: postgresql, openlayers, postgis, geoserver

I have published a shapefile "ind_adm2" in geoserver as Postgis(postgres database), It can be accessed as webpage using OpenLayers code given below. Now I need to edit the shapefile on webpage itself and save the edited(updated) things in Postgres database. Can anyone help !!

I tried using wfs URL of geoserver but unable to select the feature.

```
<html>
     <head>
       <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
       <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Layer Name1",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
         utility = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Layer Name2",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iirs/ows?", {layers: 'iirs:ind_adm2', 
    transparent:"true"}, {isBaseLayer:false} );

      map.addLayers([basemap,utility]);
      map.zoomToMaxExtent();

  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Its expected to select any polygon then edit there itself and update the edits in postgres database.

Comment: Your code is using OpenLayers 2

Comment: map is displayed, with the layer I am accessing from geoserver

Comment: so i think there is no issue with above code, already map from postgis database is displayed, now i need to select and edit the polygons followed by updating the same in database

Comment: You won't be able to edit features on a raster source such as WMS.  You will need to use a vector source such as WFS then you can edit using OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.

Comment: thanks @Mike, but I am using WFS url from geoserver.  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iirs/ows?

Comment: You are requesting WMS from the geoserver `new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS`

Comment: YEAH, there's mistake and should i request base layer also as WFS ?

Comment: No, you only need vector format for features you need to edit.

Comment: @Mike can you suggest some links to request WFS from geoserver. I am new to these and not didn't found suitable link.

Answer (score 0):

As what you need will be much more complex than your existing code you should update that to the latest version of OpenLayers (currently 5.3.0) and develop with that.  It is easier to get started using the full build https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html which is very similar to using versions 3 and 4 so you will be able to reuse examples from those versions.  For help about editing WFS here's one question with links a tutorial and some examples [Javascript editing WFS from GeoServer using OpenLayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615490/javascript-editing-wfs-from-geoserver-using-openlayers/37684432)

```
  <html>
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
       <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
       <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
       <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">

    var basemap = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
            params: {
                'LAYERS': 'basic'
            },
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            ratio: 1
        })
    });

    var utility = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iirs/ows",
            params: {
                'LAYERS': 'iirs:ind_adm2',
                'TRANSPARENT': 'true'
            },
            projection: 'EPSG:4326'
        })
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [basemap],  utility],
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326'
        })
    });

    map.getView().fit(map.getView().getProjection().getExtent());

  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: thanks alot mike, but i have a doubt in your code you are also requesting as WMS from Geoserver, does the displayed map will be WFS ?

Comment: I've simply converted your existing code to OpenLayers 5.  I don't know the WFS capabilities of your server.

Comment: ok mike! I was going through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387422/display-wfs-layer-in-ol3 , he had a solution but the WFS url he is getting doesn't match my WFS url format i.e like this "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iirs/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=iirs%3Aind_adm2&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson" do you have idea about it ?